# Bring back yellow gear icon in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS2010, how to bring back the Visual Studio's yellow gear icon ?
It looked nice and warm in VS2005/2008.
This new purple icon makes my eyes sore..

I want to write .NET codes without being constantly reminded of Eclipse..

Comment: Are you talking about the yellow traingle with exclamation mark in it?

Comment: @Slaks I think he meant the logo.

Comment: I assume he means the squared-off sideways 8 ribbon that appears in the taskbar, window corner, etc. It's not a gear and it's only partly yellow, but I can't imagine what else he would be talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're right, and you want to monkey with the logo icon, you can right-click on the program, choose "Properties", go to the "Shortcut" tab and click "Change Icon". Then browse to the old VS executable and pick your old logo. I don't know how many places will pick up the change though.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I replaced the embedded icon in devenv.exe and it looks good now. More in: http://jesonmartajaya.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/c-how-to-make-vs2010-look-and-feel-like-vs2008/